# Ubuntu 15.04 freezes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 15.04, bug-reporting

I have looked at other similar questions asking about how to fix generic "Ubuntu xx.xx randomly freezes" but have not been able to conclusively find an answer to this exact problem: Ubuntu 15.04 seems to freeze randomly on me.

I don't know exactly what's happening, but it would appear Ubuntu is still receiving input (at least from the keyboard): at the end of the second syslog paste (see the link to pastebin), you can see I attempted <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd>, but for whatever reason that failed. Attempting to switch to a console via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does nothing.

The system logs don't even seem to show the same cause each time. See below for system stats and two crash logs from syslog.

If there is any additional information I can provide to assist in troubleshooting, I'll do my best to add it ASAP. Thank you for the help -- this issue is especially frustrating as I'm trying to run a web server from this machine.

## Computer Specs

```
-Computer-
Model: Dell XPS 8700
Processor       : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Memory      : 7994MB (1226MB used)
Operating System        : Ubuntu 15.04
-Display-
Resolution      : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Unknown
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
-Input Devices-
 DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard
 DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard
 DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse
 HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm     : 3=
 HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm     : 7=
-SCSI Disks-
ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1
HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GHB0N
Generic- Compact Flash
Generic- SM/xD-Picture
Generic- SD/MMC
Generic- M.S./M.S.Pro/HG

-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 3.19.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Compiled        : #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015
C Library       : Unknown
Default C Compiler      : GNU C Compiler version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 
Distribution        : Ubuntu 15.04
```

## Graphics Card/Driver

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208 [GeForce GT 720]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

## syslog

```
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804063] ------------[ cut here ]------------
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804068] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-SKpZC9/linux-3.19.0/kernel/watchdog.c:290 watchdog_overflow_callback+0x92/0xc0()
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804069] Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804070] Modules linked in: ctr ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec arc4 snd_hwdep nouveau ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw snd_pcm intel_rapl iosf_mbi mxm_wmi snd_seq_midi x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_seq_midi_event intel_powerclamp snd_rawmidi ath3k wmi btusb coretemp ath mac80211 kvm_intel kvm cfg80211 ttm drm_kms_helper bluetooth drm snd_seq dcdbas i2c_algo_bit mei_me snd_seq_device snd_timer crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei aesni_intel snd video shpchp aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul soundcore mac_hid lpc_ich glue_helper serio_raw ablk_helper cryptd parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804096] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804096] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804097]  ffffffff81a9ed48 ffff88021ec05ab0 ffffffff817c45cf 0000000000000007
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804098]  ffff88021ec05b00 ffff88021ec05af0 ffffffff81076a6a 0000000000000000
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804100]  ffff880216014800 0000000000000000 ffff88021ec05c40 ffff88021ec05ef8
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804101] Call Trace:
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804102]    [] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804107]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804108]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804110]  [] watchdog_overflow_callback+0x92/0xc0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804112]  [] __perf_event_overflow+0x8c/0x220
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804115]  [] ? x86_perf_event_set_period+0xca/0x170
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804116]  [] perf_event_overflow+0x14/0x20
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804118]  [] intel_pmu_handle_irq+0x1ba/0x3a0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804120]  [] perf_event_nmi_handler+0x2b/0x50
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804121]  [] nmi_handle+0x80/0x120
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804123]  [] default_do_nmi+0x4a/0x140
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804124]  [] do_nmi+0xf8/0x170
20:52:04 kernel: [ 106Operating System
----------------

0.804126]  [] end_repeat_nmi+0x1a/0x1e
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804127]  [] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x4f/0x90
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804128]  [] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x4f/0x90
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804129]  [] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x4f/0x90
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804129]  >    [] nouveau_fantog_update+0x94/0x180 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804154]  [] nouveau_fantog_set+0x35/0x40 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804162]  [] nouveau_fan_update+0x101/0x220 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804170]  [] nouveau_therm_fan_set+0x19/0x20 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804177]  [] nouveau_therm_update+0xbd/0x340 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804185]  [] ? alarm_timer_callback+0x68/0xe0 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804192]  [] nouveau_therm_alarm+0x1a/0x20 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804200]  [] nv04_timer_alarm_trigger+0x120/0x170 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804208]  [] nv04_timer_alarm+0x7b/0xe0 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804215]  [] nouveau_fantog_update+0x15f/0x180 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804216]  [] ? native_sched_clock+0x2a/0x90
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804223]  [] nouveau_fantog_alarm+0x1a/0x20 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804230]  [] nv04_timer_alarm_trigger+0x120/0x170 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804237]  [] nv04_timer_intr+0x6b/0x90 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804245]  [] nouveau_mc_intr+0x12c/0x1b0 [nouveau]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804247]  [] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x77/0x1a0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804248]  [] handle_irq_event+0x41/0x70
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804250]  [] handle_edge_irq+0x6e/0x120
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804251]  [] handle_irq+0x22/0x40
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804253]  [] do_IRQ+0x4f/0xf0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804254]  [] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804254]    [] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x65/0x160
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804257]  [] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x51/0x160
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804258]  [] cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804260]  [] cpu_startup_entry+0x311/0x3b0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804262]  [] rest_init+0x77/0x80
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804264]  [] start_kernel+0x487/0x494
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804266]  [] ? early_idt_handler_array+0x120/0x120
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804267]  [] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804269]  [] x86_64_start_kernel+0x143/0x152
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1060.804269] ---[ end trace 5ffc33a915606ef1 ]---
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594479] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [thermald:888]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594481] Modules linked in: ctr ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec arc4 snd_hwdep nouveau ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw snd_pcm intel_rapl iosf_mbi mxm_wmi snd_seq_midi x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_seq_midi_event intel_powerclamp snd_rawmidi ath3k wmi btusb coretemp ath mac80211 kvm_intel kvm cfg80211 ttm drm_kms_helper bluetooth drm snd_seq dcdbas i2c_algo_bit mei_me snd_seq_device snd_timer crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei aesni_intel snd video shpchp aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul soundcore mac_hid lpc_ich glue_helper serio_raw ablk_helper cryptd parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594508] CPU: 3 PID: 888 Comm: thermald Tainted: G        W      3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594508] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594509] task: ffff8802123475c0 ti: ffff88020ac78000 task.ti: ffff88020ac78000
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594510] RIP: 0010:[]  [] generic_exec_single+0xd6/0x190
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594515] RSP: 0018:ffff88020ac7bc58  EFLAGS: 00000202
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594516] RAX: 0000000000000100 RBX: 0000000000000292 RCX: 0000000000000001
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594516] RDX: ffff88021ecce040 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000292
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594517] RBP: ffff88020ac7bc88 R08: ffff88021ecce028 R09: 0000000000000000
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594518] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000292
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594518] R13: ffff88020ac7bc28 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000080000
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594519] FS:  00007f92c7c8b700(0000) GS:ffff88021ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594520] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594520] CR2: 00007f1877ca6010 CR3: 00000000dd92c000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594521] Stack:
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594522]  0000000000000000 ffffffff813e6310 ffff88020ac7bcc8 0000000000000003
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594523]  0000000000000000 ffffffff813e6310 ffff88020ac7bcb8 ffffffff810f4787
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594524]  ffff880212776020 ffffffff81216474 ffff88020ac7bd14 ffff88020ac7bd10
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594525] Call Trace:
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594529]  [] ? ucs2_strncmp+0x60/0x60
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594530]  [] ? ucs2_strncmp+0x60/0x60
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594532]  [] smp_call_function_single+0x67/0xa0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594534]  [] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594535]  [] rdmsr_on_cpu+0x4e/0x70
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594537]  [] sys_get_curr_temp+0x39/0x90 [x86_pkg_temp_thermal]
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594540]  [] thermal_zone_get_temp+0x6e/0x110
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594542]  [] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594543]  [] temp_show+0x1e/0x40
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594546]  [] dev_attr_show+0x20/0x60
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594549]  [] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x40
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594552]  [] sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xb6/0x150
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594553]  [] kernfs_seq_show+0x23/0x30
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594555]  [] seq_read+0xcd/0x3b0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594556]  [] kernfs_fop_read+0x105/0x170
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594558]  [] ? security_file_permission+0x84/0xa0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594561]  [] __vfs_read+0x18/0x50
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594562]  [] vfs_read+0x8a/0x140
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594563]  [] SyS_read+0x46/0xb0
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594565]  [] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
20:52:04 kernel: [ 1071.594566] Code: c2 00 52 01 00 48 03 14 c5 40 86 d2 81 48 89 de 48 89 df e8 1d 4b 2d 00 84 c0 74 0b e9 9c 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 f3 90 f6 43 18 01  f8 31 c0 48 83 c4 20 5b 41 5c 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 63 c4 
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoting known real-time threads.
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1676 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1675 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1561 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:11 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoted 4 threads.
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoting known real-time threads.
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1676 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1675 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1561 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:21 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoted 4 threads.
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoting known real-time threads.
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1676 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1675 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1561 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:31 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoted 4 threads.
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584442] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [thermald:888]
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584444] Modules linked in: ctr ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec arc4 snd_hwdep nouveau ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw snd_pcm intel_rapl iosf_mbi mxm_wmi snd_seq_midi x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_seq_midi_event intel_powerclamp snd_rawmidi ath3k wmi btusb coretemp ath mac80211 kvm_intel kvm cfg80211 ttm drm_kms_helper bluetooth drm snd_seq dcdbas i2c_algo_bit mei_me snd_seq_device snd_timer crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel mei aesni_intel snd video shpchp aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul soundcore mac_hid lpc_ich glue_helper serio_raw ablk_helper cryptd parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584469] CPU: 3 PID: 888 Comm: thermald Tainted: G        W    L 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584470] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584471] task: ffff8802123475c0 ti: ffff88020ac78000 task.ti: ffff88020ac78000
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584472] RIP: 0010:[]  [] generic_exec_single+0xd6/0x190
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584477] RSP: 0018:ffff88020ac7bc58  EFLAGS: 00000202
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584477] RAX: 0000000000000100 RBX: 0000000000000292 RCX: 0000000000000001
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584478] RDX: ffff88021ecce040 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000292
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584478] RBP: ffff88020ac7bc88 R08: ffff88021ecce028 R09: 0000000000000000
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584479] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000292
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584480] R13: ffff88020ac7bc28 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000080000
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584480] FS:  00007f92c7c8b700(0000) GS:ffff88021ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584481] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584482] CR2: 00007f1877ca6010 CR3: 00000000dd92c000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584483] Stack:
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584483]  0000000000000000 ffffffff813e6310 ffff88020ac7bcc8 0000000000000003
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584484]  0000000000000000 ffffffff813e6310 ffff88020ac7bcb8 ffffffff810f4787
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584485]  ffff880212776020 ffffffff81216474 ffff88020ac7bd14 ffff88020ac7bd10
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584486] Call Trace:
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584490]  [] ? ucs2_strncmp+0x60/0x60
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584491]  [] ? ucs2_strncmp+0x60/0x60
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584493]  [] smp_call_function_single+0x67/0xa0
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584495]  [] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584496]  [] rdmsr_on_cpu+0x4e/0x70
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584498]  [] sys_get_curr_temp+0x39/0x90 [x86_pkg_temp_thermal]
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584501]  [] thermal_zone_get_temp+0x6e/0x110
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584503]  [] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584504]  [] temp_show+0x1e/0x40
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584507]  [] dev_attr_show+0x20/0x60
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584509]  [] ? mutex_lock+0x16/0x40
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584512]  [] sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xb6/0x150
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584514]  [] kernfs_seq_show+0x23/0x30
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584515]  [] seq_read+0xcd/0x3b0
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584517]  [] kernfs_fop_read+0x105/0x170
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584519]  [] ? security_file_permission+0x84/0xa0
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584521]  [] __vfs_read+0x18/0x50
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584523]  [] vfs_read+0x8a/0x140
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584524]  [] SyS_read+0x46/0xb0
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584526]  [] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
20:52:32 kernel: [ 1099.584527] Code: c2 00 52 01 00 48 03 14 c5 40 86 d2 81 48 89 de 48 89 df e8 1d 4b 2d 00 84 c0 74 0b e9 9c 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 f3 90 f6 43 18 01  f8 31 c0 48 83 c4 20 5b 41 5c 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 63 c4 
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806889] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 0} (detected by 3, t=15002 jiffies, g=110501, c=110500, q=0)
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806894] Task dump for CPU 0:
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806895] swapper/0       R  running task        0     0      0 0x00000008
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806897]  0000000000000010 0000000000000202 ffffffff81c03e68 0000000000000018
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806898]  ffffffff816660d1 0000000000000000 000000f3264c1dd7 ffffffff81c03e98
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806899]  ffffffff81d29460 ffff88021ec1bc00 ffffffff81c00000 ffffffff81ca9880
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806900] Call Trace:
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806905]  [] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x51/0x160
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806906]  [] ? cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806908]  [] ? cpu_startup_entry+0x311/0x3b0
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806911]  [] ? rest_init+0x77/0x80
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806914]  [] ? start_kernel+0x487/0x494
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806916]  [] ? early_idt_handler_array+0x120/0x120
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806918]  [] ? x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
20:52:36 kernel: [ 1103.806919]  [] ? x86_64_start_kernel+0x143/0x152
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoting known real-time threads.
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1676 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1675 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1561 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:41 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoted 4 threads.
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoting known real-time threads.
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1676 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1675 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Successfully demoted thread 1561 of process 1561 (n/a).
20:52:51 rtkit-daemon[1562]: Demoted 4 threads.
```

See http://pastebin.com/TNJrdDEj for second crash log (system crashed less than 5 minutes after booting up). Could not post here as it passed the character limit.

Comment: How often does it freeze ?

Comment: It would appear the issue had to do with the graphics driver -- at least for now, system uptime is ~40 hours and no crash. It had been freezing anywhere from 5 minutes from booting to 3 hours. How do I mark this question as already solved?

Comment: Put what you have done to fix the issue in the answer field below and you will be able to mark the question as solved ;)

Comment: Problem is, I don't know what I did that fixed it :P I'll put something together this weekend when I have time though. I'm pretty sure, from the logs and from the stuff I did do, that it was in some way related to the `nouveau vs nvidia` drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not install a proprietary NVIDIA driver.
Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.